# Can't load FMOD on Android using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, fmod, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to add FMOD support to a sample Native-Activity Application in Visual Studio 2015 Preview.

I changed *VC++ Directories* to point at fmod headers and linked against libfmod.so like this:
[image]
The code remains unchanged except for the single `#include "fmod.hpp"` and compiles without errors.

However, the application does not launch at all.
All I get is: *Unfortunately, Android2.Packaging has stopped.*
**If I simply remove "fmod" from the Library Dependencies, the sample application works as expected**, because for the moment I'm not using any symbols from the library.

Here is the log from the Output window (it looks like libfmod.so is never loaded):

```
Loaded 'C:\Users\Anon\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Android2\x86\Debug\linker'
Loaded 'libc.so'
Loaded 'libstdc++.so'
Loaded 'libm.so'
Loaded 'liblog.so'
Loaded 'libcutils.so'
Loaded 'libgccdemangle.so'
Loaded 'libcorkscrew.so'
Loaded 'libutils.so'
Loaded 'libbinder.so'
Loaded 'libhardware.so'
Loaded 'libmemtrack.so'
Loaded 'libz.so'
Loaded 'libandroidfw.so'
Loaded 'libexpat.so'
Loaded 'libstlport.so'
Loaded 'libnativehelper.so'
Loaded 'libnetutils.so'
Loaded 'libsync.so'
Loaded 'libui.so'
Loaded 'libGLES_trace.so'
Loaded 'libEGL.so'
Loaded 'libGLESv2.so'
Loaded 'libgui.so'
Loaded 'libinput.so'
Loaded 'libcamera_metadata.so'
Loaded 'libcamera_client.so'
Loaded 'libpng.so'
Loaded 'libft2.so'
Loaded 'libjpeg.so'
Loaded 'libgabi++.so'
Loaded 'libicuuc.so'
Loaded 'libicui18n.so'
Loaded 'libskia.so'
Loaded 'libsqlite.so'
Loaded 'libGLESv1_CM.so'
Loaded 'libETC1.so'
Loaded 'libwpa_client.so'
Loaded 'libhardware_legacy.so'
Loaded 'libselinux.so'
Loaded 'libsonivox.so'
Loaded 'libcrypto.so'
Loaded 'libssl.so'
Loaded 'libstagefright_foundation.so'
Loaded 'libspeexresampler.so'
Loaded 'libaudioutils.so'
Loaded 'libmedia.so'
Loaded 'libusbhost.so'
Loaded 'libharfbuzz_ng.so'
Loaded 'libLLVM.so'
Loaded 'libbcinfo.so'
Loaded 'libbcc.so'
Loaded 'libRS.so'
Loaded 'libRScpp.so'
Loaded 'libhwui.so'
Loaded 'libandroid_runtime.so'
Loaded 'libdvm.so'
Loaded 'libjavacore.so'
Loaded 'libdrmframework.so'
Loaded 'libdrmframework_jni.so'
Loaded 'libconnectivitymanager.so'
Loaded 'libstagefright_omx.so'
Loaded 'libstagefright_yuv.so'
Loaded 'libvorbisidec.so'
Loaded 'libpowermanager.so'
Loaded 'libstagefright_enc_common.so'
Loaded 'libstagefright_avc_common.so'
Loaded 'libstagefright.so'
Loaded 'libmtp.so'
Loaded 'libexif.so'
Loaded 'libstagefright_amrnb_common.so'
Loaded 'libmedia_jni.so'
Loaded 'libjhead.so'
Loaded 'libjhead_jni.so'
Loaded 'librs_jni.so'
Loaded 'libandroid.so'
Loaded 'libjnigraphics.so'
Loaded 'libwebviewchromium.so'
Loaded 'libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so'
Loaded 'libjavacrypto.so'
Loaded 'libpixelflinger.so'
Loaded 'libGLES_android.so'
=thread-group-added,id="i1"GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i586-pc-mingw32msvc --target=i686-pc-linux-android".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html>.
=thread-group-started,id="i1",pid="1589"=thread-created,id="1",group-id="i1"=tsv-created,name="trace_timestamp",initial="0"\n=thread-created,id="2",group-id="i1"[New Thread 1593]
=thread-created,id="3",group-id="i1"[New Thread 1594]
=thread-created,id="4",group-id="i1"[New Thread 1595]
=thread-created,id="5",group-id="i1"[New Thread 1596]
=thread-created,id="6",group-id="i1"[New Thread 1597]
=thread-created,id="7",group-id="i1"[New Thread 1598]
=thread-created,id="8",group-id="i1"[New Thread 1599]
=thread-created,id="9",group-id="i1"[New Thread 1600]
=thread-created,id="10",group-id="i1"[New Thread 1601]
=thread-group-exited,id="i1"The program '' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Some logs from Device Manager:
[image]

Am I missing something?